# CutePDF giving error message "Invalid PDF file!" when splitting pdf

Tags: pdf-generation, cutepdf

I have copied the code for using CutePDF to get the first page of a multi-page PDF using the document.splitDPF from another project, and despite it working in the other project, the exact same code is failing with the error message "Invalid PDF file!" in my new project.

Answer (score 0):

CutePDF is installed as a COM+ component, which means it has it's own permissions independent of whatever application is running it (may be Network Service, maybe something else entirely).  Check and make sure that the account that CutePDF is running as, has read/write permission to the directory where the file is.